# How to make XStream parse partial input from StAX

Tags: java, xml, xstream, stax

I am new to Stax and XStream. I am trying to unmarshall some common elements from huge XML stream (there might be between 1.5 million and 2.5 million elements to unmarshal)

I have tried to Stax to parse the stream to get to an element of interest and then call xStream to unMarshall the XML up to the EndElement.

```
XMLStreamReader reader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(fis);
            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                if (reader.isStartElement() && reader.getLocalName().toLowerCase().equals("person")) {
                    break;
                }
                reader.next();
            }

            StaxDriver sd = new StaxDriver();
            AbstractPullReader rd = sd.createStaxReader(reader);
            XStream xstream = new XStream(sd);
            xstream.registerConverter(new PersonConverter());
            Person p = (Person) xstream.unmarshal(rd);
```

I create a test input 
    `<Persons>
        <Person>
          <name>A</name>
        </Person>
        <Person>
          <name>B</name>
        </Person>
        <Person>
          <name>C</name>
        </Person>
    </Persons>`

The problem with this, is that first my converter is not called. Second, I get a CannotResolveClassException for the element "name" in Person and XStream doesn't create my Person object. 
What did I miss in my code?

Comment: Hi, I am also facing a similar issue while using the `XMLStreamReader`. I am not sure how to `Look Ahead` using the `XMLStreamReader`. Have you found the answer to this? If so please provide your response. I have posted my question here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67667516/stax-xmlstreamreader-check-for-the-next-event-without-moving-ahead

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate an `AbstractPullReader` it will read the first open-element event from the stream, establishing the "root" element. Because you've already read the first `Person` event it will advance to the next one (`name`), which it doesn't know how to unmarshal.

You'll have to do two things to make your example work:

First, alias the element name `Person` to your java class

```
xstream.alias("Person", Person.class);
```

Second, only advance the SAX cursor up to the element *before* the one you want to read:

```
while (reader.hasNext()) {         
    if (reader.isStartElement() && reader.getLocalName().equals("Persons")) {            
        break;
    }
    reader.next();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That works but then I am compelled to stop one element before the one I would like to parse. What if Persons might contain a few optional elements as its first children. StAX readers API do not provide a "look ahead" method.